# How can change sender email Address?

Tags: visual-workflow

[image]

I made Trigger Flow and Schedule Flow using Email Alert using with email template.

Addly, I want change sender email address, so use custom email in Flow Action, add the sender email, but still cannot change email address.

how can i change sender's email address?

Regards, CKJ

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the 'Flow Core Action: Send Email' action node in your Flow. You can specify the sender, just be sure to check you org-wide addresses.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5